# Array - get only visible Cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to store only visible data into an array that will be used in other Workbook, as the following part of coding:

```
Dim arr0 As Variant
lastrow = wk.Sheets("database").Range("E10000").End(xlUp).Row


arr0 = Sheets("database").Range("A2:G" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellsTypeVisible)
```

Although it seems pretty sense, the array stores all data, not only the one I'm willing to.
Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Comment: You can't safely get an array using `Value` if the source range contains multiple areas - you will only get the first area.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub rng_to_arr()
Dim arr() As Variant
lastrow = Sheets("database").Range("E10000").End(xlUp).Row
Count = 0
For Each cell In Sheets("database").Range("A2:G" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ReDim Preserve arr(Count)
    arr(Count) = cell
    Count = Count + 1
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI you have the count of cells before entering the loop, so you can `ReDim` the array to the final size and avoid the (expensive) `ReDim Preserve` step